Collective nouns in use
We can say "the team is or are" depending on how we see it. What if we say "A team"? Then only "is" is correct,right?

A team can be regarded as a singular or plural entity, as you have noted. The use of the indefinite article ('A team') makes no difference to that. A team's form describes how a team are playing at that point in the season; there are many people who can say that a team are playing badly. There are few people who can say why they play badly.

Why do you use the term 'compound noun'?

Also, if a team is playing at home, it is playing at its own ground.

Thank you very much

The rules for collective nouns change with time and with locale.
Consider something as simple as "the faculty [is/are] meeting." In Googles Ngram viewer, they run about neck-and-neck, but about 1980, "are" was more common.
However, I'd agree with your statement that, when using the article, a, the singular verb is more natural, and Ngram bears that out: "a team is" occurs about 10 times more frequently than "a team are," yet "the team is" occurs about five times more frequently than "the team are,"
